# Electric field between two displaced, coaxial cylinders?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

This is not about the classic coax cable homework problem. I'm wondering how to find the electric field between two *displaced* coaxial cylinders, shown below.
[image]

How would it be affected by adding cylinders of a dielectric inside the electrodes (dark gray)?